# Why does the exported video still have control buttons, causing the screen to be too large?

Tags: plotting

towerofPisa =
[image];

gali =
[image];

```
ani = Manipulate[
  Graphics[{Inset[towerofPisa, Center, Center, {1, 1}], 
    Inset[gali, {.615, .88}, Center, {.05, .05}], 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], Disk[{.65, .85 - 1/2 .98 t^2}, m1/30], 
    Disk[{.72, .85 - 1/2 .98 t^2}, m2/30]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}],
  {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 1.27, ControlType -> Trigger},
  {{m1, .15, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(1\)]\)"}, .1, .8},
  {{m2, .3, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\)"}, .1, .8}, 
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "test1.mp4"], ani, 
 "ControlAppearance" -> None, "time" -> None, "FrameRate" -> 18, 
 "AnimationDuration" -> 20]
```

[image]

The exported video appears as shown in the image, with the presence of control buttons causing the frame to be very large. How can I remove the buttons to return the video size to normal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a bug. Here is a workaround. Change

```
{{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 1.27, ControlType -> Trigger},
```

to

```
Row[{Control[{{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 1.27, ControlType -> Trigger}]}],
```

And now the trigger do not show any more.

V 14 on windows 10.  This is link to the [mp4 file](https://12000.org/tmp/feb_17_2024/test1.mp4)

[image]

Code

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
towerofPisa = Import["towerofPisa.png"];
gali = Import["gali.png"];

ani = Manipulate[
  Graphics[{Inset[towerofPisa, Center, Center, {1, 1}], 
    Inset[gali, {.615, .88}, Center, {.05, .05}], 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], Disk[{.65, .85 - 1/2  .98  t^2}, m1/30], 
    Disk[{.72, .85 - 1/2  .98  t^2}, m2/30]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}],
  Row[{Control[{{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 1.27, ControlType -> Trigger}]}],
  {{m1, .15, "m1"}, .1, .8},
  {{m2, .3, "m2"}, .1, .8},
  SaveDefinitions -> True]

Export["test1.mp4",ani,"time"->None,"AnimationDuration"->5,"ControlAppearance"->None]
```